# Want to be one of the first of the 50?

Tags: grammar

I have a question
We are inviting people to join our platform and we want to pick the first 50 artists

In our advertisement we are using

**“ Want to be one of the first of the 50?”**

Is this sentence grammatically okay?
Somthing sounds wrong and I don’t know what is

Comment: @FumbleFingers great explanation. Should we use “first 50s” or just first 50? Why and why not?

Comment: @FumbleFingers isn’t that better if we say “want to be one of the first 50 artists?”

Comment: @FumbleFingers you’re amazing. Thank you for your explanation

Comment: I think it's best if I post my text as an actual answer here. I wasn't sure what you were getting at originally, but from your comments it seems I guessed right.

Comment: @FumbleFingers yup. Accepted it as an answer already:))

Comment: Redundant comments deleted. Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think OP probably means *[Do you] want to be **one of the first 50**?* (not *...one of the first **of the** 50*). It probably doesn't make any difference if you're one of *the first **of the** 50* (the 2nd or 5th artist, perhaps) - even if you're the 48th or 50th, ***you will be picked*** (you just don't want to be the 51st or later, because you'll miss out on some special offer).

---

Note that in the construction ***the first N***, meaning *all items from the first to the Nth*, whatever number you specify for ***N*** is always singular (so it's ***50 artists***, not ***50s artists*** or ***50s artist*** unless you're talking about artists from the 1950s! :) But whether to explicitly specify ***artists*** after ***the first 50*** is really just a stylistic choice (assuming the context makes it obvious what we're talking about). They might just as well be *the first 50 **applicants***, or *the first 50 **people to apply***, for example. It doesn't really make any difference here.